# How to use useRef hook to remove the effect of useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-ref

I am using useRef and useEffect for learning purpose. In the AppBar, I want to color(yellow) the Navlink when clicked, using useRef. But the problem is that, how to remove effect (remove color) from first Navlink , when I select the other Navlink.
[image]

```
const history = useHistory();

const focusHomeRef = useRef(null);
const focusAdmissionRef = useRef(null);
const focusResultRef = useRef(null);
const focusAboutRef = useRef(null);
const isInitialHome = useRef(true); 

useEffect(() => {
 focusHomeRef.current.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
},[]);

function focusHome() {
 history.push("/");
 focusHomeRef.current.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
}

function focusAdmission() {
 history.push("/Admission");
 focusAdmissionRef.current.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
}

function focusResult() {
 history.push("/Result");
 focusResultRef.current.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
}

function focusAbout() {
 history.push("/About");
 focusAboutRef.current.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";


return (
 <div>
   <AppBar position="static" >
     <Toolbar>
       
       <IconButton ref={focusHomeRef} onClick={focusHome}>
         <HomeIcon style={{ color: green[500] }} />
         <Avatar alt="Remy Sharp" src="../../styles/img/faces/avatar.jpg" />
         <Typography className={classes.title} variant="h6" noWrap>
           Home
         </Typography>
       </IconButton>

       <div>
         <Button ref={focusAdmissionRef} onClick={focusAdmission}>
           <Typography>Admission</Typography>
         </Button>

         <Button ref={focusResultRef} onClick={focusResult}>
           <Typography>Results</Typography>
         </Button>

         <Button ref={focusAboutRef} onClick={focusAbout}>
           <Typography>About</Typography>
         </Button>
</div>
     </Toolbar>
   </AppBar>
</div>
```

The goal is achieved by below code lines, but its become too much lengthy and seems not a good approach.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    focusHomeRef.current.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
  });

  function focusHome() {
    history.push("/");
    //if (isInitialHome.current) {
    focusHomeRef.current.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    focusAdmissionRef.current.style.backgroundColor = "inherit";
    focusResultRef.current.style.backgroundColor = "inherit";
    focusAboutRef.current.style.backgroundColor = "inherit";
    isInitialHome.current = false;
    // }
  }

  function focusAdmission() {
    history.push("/Admission");
    focusAdmissionRef.current.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    isInitialHome.current = false;
    isInitialResult.current = false;
    isInitialAbout.current = false;
  }
```

How can I use useRef and useEffect in a better way (efficiently) in this context.

Comment: You came up with an artificial use-case for learning purposes, so there is unlikely to be an elegant solution to this non-existing problem. You can put the selected element to the state and remove background color from that one only.

Comment: I want to track a previous-ref = "inherit" and current-ref ="yellow" but unsuccessful to do that.

Comment: At the same time as you assign `backgroundColor` to it you can put the element into a state variable or even another ref, that will be your previous one on the next round

Comment: Thanks @NadiaChibrikova, you did it. Thanks for teaching me useRef. Now I understood its working.